# Parsing OpenFlow Http packet with JNetPcap

Tags: http, openflow, jnetpcap

How to parse an OpenFlow Tcp Packet with JNetPcap?

Answer (score 1):

OpenFlow is layered on TCP not HTTP.

However because jnetpcap doesn't provide OpenFlow header/structure and also jnetpcap doesn't support TCP reassembly, this is not a trivial task.

Here is what you'd have to do:

1) You would have to provide TCP reassembly code

2) Extract OpenFlow from tcp stream

Comment: This is my full code : https://github.com/hichamjabbour/JNetPcap-TcpReassembly.git